# Preventing jumps with responsive images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the **picture** element with **srcset** so the same image but with different resolution is downloaded based on the device screen size.

It's **max-width: 100%** on the image's styles so when it downloads it forces the content below to move.

Is there any way to tell the browser to reserve that space using CSS when using srcset?

I'm also interested on a JavaScript answer if it's not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: download the newest chrome. It fixes it automatically...

Comment: @Jonasw not everyone uses Chrome.

Comment: but i think firefox will follow, and i personally dont care about the rest...

Comment: @Jonasw what if you want to show some text on it or make it look like a grey rectangle before the image appears there? It's helpful to show placeholder UI elements before things are loaded.

Comment: youre right with that. If you know the image ratio, you can set image.height=window.innerWidth()*ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the image height based on the image width. So the only thing you need to know is your cameras aspect ratio. If the images have different proportions, weve got a problem...

```
ratio=9/16;
window.onload=window.onresize=function(){
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("img"),function(img){ 
         img.height=img.width*ratio;
   });
};
```